# 4th generator of U(2)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I can parametrize any $U(2)$ matrix as:

$$
M = e^{i\varphi/2}\left(\begin{matrix}
e^{i\phi_1}cos\theta & e^{i\phi_2}sin\theta \\
-e^{-i\phi_2}sin\theta & e^{-i\phi_1}cos\theta 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

To obtain the Lie algebra I derive respecto to the four parameters and evalute at the identity element, but for $\phi_2$ the generator that I get is a null matrix.

**Note:** I know that I have to obtain the Pauli matrices plus the identity (up to multiplicative factors)... so what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{e}{\mathrm{e}}$
$\newcommand{i}{\mathrm{i}}$
There's no mystery here—your calculation shows that the map $M:\mathrm{U}(1)^4\to\mathrm{U}(2)$ defined by
$$M(\phi/2,\theta,\phi_1/2,\phi_2/2)=\e^{\i\varphi/2}\e^{\i\sigma_3(\phi_1+\phi_2)/2}\e^{\i\sigma_2\theta}\e^{\i\sigma_3(\phi_1-\phi_2)/2}\text{,}$$
while surjective, does not have full rank at the identity. No such map can have full rank everywhere—engineers call this loss of rotational degrees of freedom *gimbal lock*.

To obtain a basis for the Lie algebra, you need to choose a map $M$ that has full rank at the identity, such as

$$M(\phi_0,\phi_x,\phi_y,\phi_z)=\e^{\i\phi_0}\e^{\i\phi_1\sigma_1}\e^{\i\phi_2\sigma_2}\e^{\i\phi_3\sigma_3}$$

Comment: But I don´t see how that 'loss of degrees of freedom' happened. I just impposed the condition of unitarity. And what do you mean with 'full rank at the identity'?

Comment: The Jacobian of $M$ in local coordinates is given by a $4\times 4$ matrix. The This matrix, when evaluated at the identity, must have rank $4$. A simpler situation with the same phenomenon is with representing points in space using spherical coordinates—on the zenith, the location of a point doesn't depend on the azimuth, so the Jacobian matrix between spherical and cartesian coordinates has rank two, not three.

Comment: I've never seen a Jocabian for a matrix, I've seen it for a change of coordinates as the example you cite. So how is that object and what's its function? Sorry, maybe it's a trivial question but I don't get it